# Display all product, product attribute value and attribute label of specific category id in magento

Tags: php, content-management-system, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I have successfully display all collection of products and product attribute value from a specific category ID. However I can't figure out how to display the product attribute label. The attribute labels are hard coded but I want it to be auto generated.

How can I display all product attribute value and their respective labels that are allowed to be seen on frontend?

So far this is what I've got

```
<?php
$idValue = 10;
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($idValue); //where $category_id is the id of the category
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model); //category filter
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched 
$collection->addStoreFilter(); 
?>
<table class="full-width-tbl">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Part Number</th>
        <th>Model</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php  foreach ($collection as $_product): ?>             
    <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/IndividualProduct">
        <td itemprop="name" style="display:none;"><?php echo $_product->getPart_number() ?></td>
        <td itemprop="sku"><?php echo $_product->getModel() ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

This will give you `Attributelabel-Attributecode-Attributevalue`

```
  <?php  foreach ($collection as $_product):  

    $product_id = $_product->getId();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $attributes = $product->getAttributes();


    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) { 
            $visibility = $attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront();
            $attributeLabel = $attribute->getFrontendLabel();
            $attributeValue = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            $attributeCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
if($visibility){           
 echo $attributeLabel . '-' . $attributeCode . '-' . $attributeValue; echo "<br />";  }     

    }
    endforeach
     ?>
```

Comment: this fetch all attributes, how can I sort it to only display those set Visible on Product View Page on Front-end to yes?